# Can I still save my motherboard? Some I/O are functioning, some are not

Tags: usb, motherboard, power-supply

This morning I turned off my computer with a usb cable still connected in the top usb panel, next to the power button. Over the day one of my children had put the other end (micro usb) into another usb port. I did not notice until I tried to start my computer this evening and it just didn't start. I noticed the usb cable and pulled it out.
The usb panel at the top of my pc is connected with a usb 3.0 blocked connector (not sure how to name it, connector is 2x8 female pins I think) directly to my motherboard.

My power supply has a lock on it when it detects a short circuit, I waited an hour and after that I started fine... I thought.
Here is what did not turn on:

- Monitor (neither in my graphic card, nor on board HDMI, but did work in my laptop)
- Keyboard (still worked in my laptop)
- Mouse (still worked in my laptop)
- Ethernet connection led
- Motherboard led

Here is what did turn on (led turns on):

- Wireless controller receiver
- Headphones
- Card reader
- Blue-ray burner
- Hard drives spin up
- Fans spin up
- CPU fan spins up
- Graphic card fans spin up
- Casing fans spin up
- Powersupply fan spins up

When I plug in the keyboard or mouse in the card reader, it flashes on and directly off again, same goes for the usb panel on top.

Is there something I can do to save my motherboard? It is a Z77-D3H, so I probably won't be able to find a replacement that fits the CPU :(... 
And what actually happened?

Comment: Before anything else reset it and try again. This is usually done by shorting a jumper. Read your manual.

Comment: "When I plug in the keyboard or mouse in the card reader" - You connected two ports together.  You don't mention if those two ports were connected to the card reader.  Instead of submitting a comment edit your question to provide the necessary information to answer this querstion.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I'll try that, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @Ramhound edited the question. If there is anything else I need to provide, please let me know.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Resetting did not work :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the USB cable being connected improperly has caused a short.  This allowed a higher voltage current into circuitry that couldnt handle it.  There is no magic fix for this.  It would appear the USB controller and graphics chip on your motherboard have been fried.  And there might be other issues as well, that have not become apparent.

*If* it was only the GPU and USB controller that was damaged, you could try installing a PCIe/PCI graphics card and USB card.  Alternatively,you can try replacing the motherboard, as you can still find Z77-D3H models for sale.

Unfortunately, there is no guarantee your memory and CPU have survived unscathed.  They might have been damaged as well.  These are hard to test without a compatible machine to test them in, which you obviously dont have.

Ultimately, you will have to decide for yourself if it is worth purchasing ant replacement parts.  The only other option is to simply get a new computer.

Comment: I could test my GPU in another desktop, but CPU and ram are going to be difficult :(. I'll try to salvage whatever I can. But I still hope somebody could come up with something to 'fix' it.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid While it can technically be fixed, its just not worth it.  Every electrical component would have be individually tested.  Bad components desoldered from the motherboard and replacements resoldered.  With the amount of time and effort that would take, that would cost orders of magnitude more than buying a new motherboard or computer.  And then there is the possibility of your fixes damaging something else and repeating the process all over again.

Comment: You are probably right. In that case, the risk on wasting 100 euro's on a 'second hand' while my CPU is also fried, is probably also not worth it. I guess I need to buy a new mobo with cpu and ram :'(.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid start with just the mobo.  The RAM and CPU might still work.

Comment: The CPU is socket type Ancient, and the ram is DDR3. All newer MOBO's won't be compatible with the CPU and most won't with the ram. So I either spend a lot more on a guaranteed solution, or waste 100 bucks with a big risk of spending the money on new stuff anyway.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid well good luck.  be sure to upvote and mark this question as accepted to help others in the same situation